# Is "(t 某某, s 某某)" accepted notation for showing traditional and simplified characters together?

Tags: traditional-vs-simplified, notation

I've never come across the notation "(t 某某, s 某某)" to indicate traditional and simplified Chinese characters together, so I was quite confused when I came across this on the Wikipedia page for [Fuxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuxi):

> He was also known as **Paoxi** ([t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_characters) [庖犧](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BA%96%E7%8A%A7), [s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_characters) [庖牺](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BA%96%E7%89%BA)), also romanized as **Pao-hsi**.

At first I wasn't even sure what `t` and `s` stood for. Luckily there were links [t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_characters) linked to Wikipedia page for [traditional chracters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_characters) and [s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_characters) linked to the Wikipedia page for [simplified characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_characters).

Is this common notation? Is it accepted notation?

Comment: No. It's a notation limited to wikipedia.

Comment: (繁)(簡) or (繁)(简) are the common notations.  e.g.  "庖犧" (繁);  "庖牺" (简)

Comment: @fefe But, I haven't even seen it on other wiki pages before...as far as I can recall, that is.

Comment: I have never seen this, maybe it is just a technical problem, the code is used by wiki program internally, but show unintentionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never.

Although you may think such notation is convenient, Chinese people really dislike using Latin notations in Chinese books, especially for linguistics.

They use:

- "动" instead of "v." for verbs
- "名" instead of "n." for nouns
- "繁" instead of your "t" for Traditional Chinese.